# Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key X

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I changed styles of some controls using Blend and it auto generated some styles. But for some random users this error occurs:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key
>   PivotPreviousButtonBorderBrush [Line: 0 Position: 0]

Key sometimes is `ListViewItemBackground` etc.

Why are these default resources missing in some devices? how to prevent it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListViewItemBackground` was first introduced in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (*14393*) and if your users are still using *10586*, they will encounter the error you listed above.

This is why it's always safer to generate styles targeting SDK *10586*. But if you want the new styles, like in this case, you can define them manually in your `App.xaml`.

To check all available styles and other resources, have a look at all the *generic.xaml* files under each versioning folder inside

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP

Comment: Thanks Justin. My app targets minimum 10240 and doesn't require newly introduced features. How can I know if any existing resource in my `App.xaml` is compatible with older builds?

Comment: I didn't know it's possible to target a specific SDK when generating styles

Comment: You have to run the app to find out. You can still generate styles with later sdk but you should always test on lower sdks to make sure no broken resources. There&#39;s no other way to know.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls library - you should add reference to app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was  or , i did solve it by removing it.

Basically the error was indicating line number on Xaml code.

Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TabViewButtonBackground [Line: 56 Position: 42]'